# Regex & Sed: I would like to replace a string with three conditions AND

Tags: regex, sed, replace, terminal, command-line-interface

I try to mix two conditions AND in a regex without success...

I would like to remove a `,` when the line contain three conditions:
- begins with a `,`
- contains `,,,` at the second comma
- count `9` commas in total in the line

**Example of lines to change:**

```
=> ,BRQSSQDFACKE JURFSDFGEN,,,Vitsasdfaan, 11,9660,LOCHRISTI,BELGIË,NL
=> SCURTUSDF,Daniqsdel,Mr.,Tombqsdqfsdferg, Rodqsdfqsfqst, 17,4000,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,FR
```

**Result of changed lines:**

```
=> ,BRQSSQDFACKE JURFSDFGEN,,Vitsasdfaan, 11,9660,LOCHRISTI,BELGIË,NL
=> SCURTUSDF,Daniqsdel,Mr.,Tombqsdqfsdferg, Rodqsdfqsfqst, 17,4000,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,FR
```

I tried this, but it is incomplete...

```
sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\{9\}[^,]*$/s/,//2'
```

Comment: Do you also have `=>`  in your lines?

Comment: @anubhava Nope it was just to show the lines and not to be too confused with the , in first character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best achieves with awk:

```
awk -F, '(NF==10) && ($1=="") && ($3=="") && ($4=="") { sub(/,,,/,",,",$0)}1'
```

This works because 9 commas imply 10 fields, a starting comma is an empty field and the same holds for the fields 3 and 4 (,,,).

This will only fail if field 2 is empty.

When using concatenation of the empty fields, you can reduce the above to the [solution of anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54160995/8344060)

Answer (score 5):

`awk` is more suitable for this job due to multiple conditions in a comma delimited input.

You may use:

```
awk -F, 'NF == 10 && $1 $3 $4 == "" {sub(/,,,/, ",,")} 1' file
```

```
,BRQSSQDFACKE JURFSDFGEN,,Vitsasdfaan, 11,9660,LOCHRISTI,BELGIË,NL
SCURTUSDF,Daniqsdel,Mr.,Tombqsdqfsdferg, Rodqsdfqsfqst, 17,4000,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,FR
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I put the answer of kvantour because he answered just 4 seconds sooner... But yours works very good too.

Comment: @ΩlostA  That's weird, from what I saw, this answer was 4 seconds earlier than that one.  Great `awk` solution, would be my choice :)

Comment: @Tiw: Indeed this answer was posted 4 seconds earlier than the other one :)

Comment: @anubhava But I wrote mine on a mobile. Nonetheless, this is indeed a nice short version. Question, is concatenation faster than comparison? (Not that it matters here)

Answer (score 1):

Little change to your code will do:

```
sed '/^,\([^,]*,\)\{8\}[^,]*$/s/,//3'
```

Eg:

```
$ cat file
,BRQSSQDFACKE JURFSDFGEN,,,Vitsasdfaan, 11,9660,LOCHRISTI,BELGI?,NL
SCURTUSDF,Daniqsdel,Mr.,Tombqsdqfsdferg, Rodqsdfqsfqst, 17,4000,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,FR

$ sed '/^,\([^,]*,\)\{8\}[^,]*$/s/,//3' file
,BRQSSQDFACKE JURFSDFGEN,,Vitsasdfaan, 11,9660,LOCHRISTI,BELGI?,NL
SCURTUSDF,Daniqsdel,Mr.,Tombqsdqfsdferg, Rodqsdfqsfqst, 17,4000,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,FR
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much, very useful. I put the other answer as checked because he answered just sooner... Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(,[^,]*),(,,([^,]*,[^,]*){5})$/\1\2/' file
```

Remove the second `,` if the line begins with a `,` and the second `,` is followed by `,,` and there are and only are a further five `,`'s throughout the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's/^(,[^,]*,,),(([^,]*,){5}[^,]*)$/\1\2/' file
,BRQSSQDFACKE JURFSDFGEN,,Vitsasdfaan, 11,9660,LOCHRISTI,BELGIË,NL
SCURTUSDF,Daniqsdel,Mr.,Tombqsdqfsdferg, Rodqsdfqsfqst, 17,4000,SANKT VITH,BELGIQUE,FR
```

That will work with any sed that supports `-E` for EREs, e.g. GNU sed or OSX/BSD sed.